# How long should I keep my old passport?

Tags: visas, passports, passport-renewals

How long do I need to keep my old Pakistani passport with me when travelling to Germany? I have a valid visa for Germany and my new passport number is mentioned on the visa card as well. The old passport expired in 2013. Would an immigration official still ask for it?

Comment: It's still good to have it around somewhere safe, like a safety deposit box or in an actual safe - even in your home country. While you don't ever need it at the airport, there are times (such as if you naturalize or get a permanent residence status) when they might ask for it to see evidence of long term travel. So don't ever throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to present an expired passport if it contains a visa that is not expired and is still valid for entry into Germany. You still need a separate currently valid passport.

If you are carrying a new currently valid passport which contains a valid visa, there is no reason to carry the expired passport as well.